Severe usability issues with the Stack Overflow Survey 2024 pages on narrow screens
For instance, the first page. At the bottom there's the index - but it's not clear that there's a horizontal scroll bar which is only accessible when scrolling to the bottom:

which makes it feel like the other sections are going to be further down - but the user then has to scroll to the bottom to get to the horizontal scroll bar, then scroll across and hope that they don't scroll too far (as they can't see what they're scrolling):

only to then scroll back up again to see the content:


Likewise, the charts aren't responsive (enough) so they end up looking like this - the labels are hard to read:

This is even worse on the Professional Developers page where the visible part of the labels are identical, and the headings are also cut off:


The screenshots were taken on Edge 126.0.2592.113 on Windows 10, but the behaviour is the same on Chrome 127.0.6533.64 on Android 14.
